# Tabela em html com classes do excel

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Gostaria de saber se existe classes pronta do bootstrap ou alguma outra biblioteca que deixasse as tabelas com a formatação igual a do excel.

Comment: como assim igual ao excel?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/7-jquery-microsoft-excel-type-plugins/

Comment: font padrão do excel as linhas pretas entre as linhas e colunas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar este framework :

https://www.sitepoint.com/7-jquery-microsoft-excel-type-plugins/

Ele não necessáriamente é somente classes css como o bootstrap, mas vai muito alem:

> - Colunas redimensionáveis
> - Cabeçalhos de estilo Excel que o usuário ou o programador podem ocultar
> - Pode ser exibido no modo zebra-striped para melhor apresentação
> - Os dados podem ser passados para inicializar a planilha
> - O usuário ou o programador podem adicionar e excluir linhas e colunas
> - Ao contrário de outras planilhas, exiba apenas quantas linhas e colunas você precisa.
> - Adicione ou exclua-os no seu script conforme necessário, ou permita que um usuário o faça.
> - Os dados podem ser excluídos, copiados e colados, de / para uma
>     única célula ou uma linha inteira, dentro de uma planilha ou entre
>     múltiplas planilhas Interação do teclado (teclas Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V,
>     Enter e Tab / Shift + Tab) Os dados podem ser recuperados em uma
>     matriz bidimensional de cordas Múltiplas planilhas podem ser exibidas
>     em uma página API totalmente exposta

**Um exemplo de código feito com ele:**

Ao invés de uma tabela no seu html, você terá que inserir uma DIV:

`<div id = "contents" style = "margin-bottom: 20px">`

O segredo de como ele irá se comportar está no código javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {  
         var aData = [ [ "Redwood City", "300", "true" ], [ "San Francisco", "100", "true" ], [ "San Jose", "500", "false" ] ];
         var oTable = $( "div#contents" ).spreadsheet( 
          { rows: 0, cols: 0, data: aData, zebra_striped: true, read_only: false, rowheader: true, colheader: true } );
         oTable.setNumeric( 1, true );
         $( "div#contents2" ).spreadsheet( 
          { rows: 10, cols: 10, data: null, zebra_striped: false, read_only: false, rowheader: true, colheader: true } );
    } );
```

> Cada parâmetro desse faz algum tipo de ação ao inicializar o framework
>   na div "contents"

Para mais informações de parâmetros veja na documentação:

https://github.com/TanyaWebDesign/SpreadSheet

Vale lembrar que ele depende do framework jQuery.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]